# Out of the function, array of class variable is return null in java

Tags: java

In my java class I declare a class as array and in a function I assign values to the array of class but out of the function in the class it retrun null. How to access the class array.

The declared class of array variable is inbuild final class in java(https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker)

Code sample:

```
    public class Sample{

        Marker redMarker[]; // Marker is the public final class 

   // https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker

        void function1(){
            for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
                redMarker[i] = map.addMarker(.......);
            }   
        }       

        void function2(){
           if(condition){
                if(redMarker!=null){
                    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
                    redMarker[i].setVisible(false);
                    }   
                }
                else{
                    // here I get redMarker is Null.
                }
           }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should declare the Marker redMarker[]; array size

Modify your function2() like below.

```
    void function1(){
       if(condition){
            if(redMarker!=null){

            }
            else{
                redMarker = new Marker[array.length]; // added this line of code.
            }
       }
    }
```

Modify your function1() like below.

```
 void function1(){
        if(redMarker ==null){
             redMarker = new Marker[array.length]; // added this line of code.
        }
        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
            redMarker[i] = map.addMarker(.......);
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to first initialize the array

```
Marker redMarker[];
```

Something like

```
Marker redMarker[] = new Marker[someSize];
```

Then add values

```
for (int i = 0; i < someSize; i++){
    redMarker[i] = new Marker();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`redMarker` is a data member, it's value defaults to `null` unless you initialize it in a constructor or inline.

E.g.:

```
public class Sample{
    Marker redMarker[];

    public Sample(int numOfMarkers) {
        redMarker = new Marker[numOfMarkers];
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your methods aren't static, you will need a constructor doing the following:

```
public Sample() {
    redMarker = new Marker[<put the length in here];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If You are testing `if(redMarker!=null)`, then it is quite obvious that the `else` block is executed only if redMarker actually is `null`.

Everything is working as it should, the fault is probably in Your logic.

Answer (score 0):

check on function1 is it still null?

if so then you have not initialized your redMarker